# localizing custom enum property

Tags: c#, .net

I have property

```
public MyEnumType MyType {get; set;}
```

where MyEnumType is

```
public enum MyEnumType
{
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Three = 3,       
}
```

is it possible to localize MyType property without modification of MyEnumType

Comment: what do you mean by "localize" ?

Comment: What is `MoneyTransactionType`? and localize what? Where? how do you use it? In which control? Win/Wpf/Web ?

Comment: You can either use [`DisplayAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.aspx) and write custom code to access them, or you can write custom code to do a lookup based on the name of the enum value.

Answer (score 0):

It is not. It is not meant to. That is not output text, that are in program names.

This is not localization (translation of output), what you would do is translate class names in the source code.

Localizing the output you can do with a usual localiazation framework. Depends on output technology.

Comment: Your answer is really unclear. Why is it "not meant to"? I use `DisplayAttribute` on my enum values and the attributes are consumed by clients, be it a HTML page or JSON serialiser.

Comment: He means that the enumeration value usually is not something that's shown to the user of the application and thus is not meant to be localized. It's like one would translate class names for the international market.

Comment: Exactly. Also "DIsplayAttribute" does not translate the enum itself - which is asked for here.

Comment: I'm not sure about that, I suppose the question is unclear too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use extension method to create your own ToString() without changing the enumeration itself.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
  public enum MyEnumType {
    One = 1,
    Two = 2,
    Three = 3,
  }

  public static class Extension {
    public static string ToLocalizedString(this MyEnumType type) {
      // check System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture 
      // if you need current culture context
      switch (type) {
        case MyEnumType.One:
          return "Ein";
        case MyEnumType.Two:
          return "Zwei";
        case MyEnumType.Three:
          return "Drei";
        default:
          throw new NotImplementedException();
      }
    }
  }

  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
      var foo = MyEnumType.One;
      Console.Out.WriteLine(foo.ToLocalizedString());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting error on using with mvc @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.MyType.ToLocalizedString(),...  ERROR MESSAGE: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to "localize" "ToString" conversion you can go for a static method of a static class

```
public static class Localization
{
  public static string ToCultureString(this MyEnumType type)
  {
     return ResourceManager.GetString(type.ToString(), Culture);
  }
}
```

! please also take care of:

- Culture statement;
- Resource files where you have translation for the cooresponded keys

rce files for cultures you need, where you are using keys defined in your enumeration

further you can use the following code:

```
  var asString =  MyObj.MyType.ToCultureString();
```